# How can you prevent or detect a merge that changes non-conflict files in git?

Tags: git

We are using a very simple git workflow where most active development happens on the same branch. As a result, when developers do a `git pull` it usually causes a merge commit. Twice in the last week we have had novice git users do a pull that resulted in merge conflicts, and then they removed all files that they did not personally work on and committed the merge. Obviously this resulted in any changes by other developers from the commits they were merging in being removed.

How can you tell if a merge commit was modified in a way that doesn't match either parent for files without a conflict? (Essentially I want to know if there's a good way to detect a "bad" merge or not.)

Is there any systematic way to keep this from happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, this command

```
git diff-tree -r --diff-filter=D --name-only $PARENT $CHILD
```

will list all files that were deleted by the `$CHILD` commit. If you iterate over all the parents of a merge commit and check that command, and they all show a deletion, then you will know that a file was deleted in the merge but not in any of the merge parents.

That said, this is an awfully specific solution to what sounds like a bigger problem with your developers and your source control. For a slightly better solution, consider teaching your developers to use `git pull --rebase` or `git fetch && git rebase`. I find merge commits hard to follow myself, and it seems like your developers do too. You could prohibit merge commits entirely, if you want.

For the best solution, have good test coverage. If your developers delete random files, it should break tests.

Comment: Yes, I have been pushing heavily for a rebase workflow prior to this just to get rid of all the useless merge commits and crazy log graph, and now am pushing for it even more so after these issues. I haven't gotten support for it because it's a hair more complex to understand than a merge, but I'll keep working on it. How do you prohibit merge commits?

Comment: Also - what if the files were added or modified, not just deleted? Or what if deletion is the correct action?

Comment: You can add a push hook that rejects merge commits: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks (I don't think GitHub supports hooks though.) But in general, there's no way to tell the difference between good code and bad code without tests. Git doesn't know when you're making a mistake and when you're not.

Comment: Sadly my company has hundreds of thousands of lines of code and not a single test. I like the idea of a hook that prevents merge commits, assuming I can get buy-in on using rebase. Thanks!

Comment: Here's an interesting article about all the work that was done at Google to get legacy code under test: http://mike-bland.com/2012/08/10/call-me-ishmael.html